# Как настроить nginx для Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, nginx

Есть проект на Yii2. Когда захожу на сайт - пишет что не найден класс, хотя по факту он есть. Подскажите что не так тут?

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name mysite.test;
    root        /var/www/html/site/web;
    index       index.php;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то что у вас "root  /var/www/html/site/web" указывает на веб, а файлы которые вы подгружаете " лежат вне web) так и задумано ? у вас я смотрю и htaccess в папке сайт, видать апач указывал DocumentRoot именно на папку сайт (который уже бросал на веб), а не на папку веб

Comment: @noname2019 апач выбросил нахрен) мне нравится nginx. Просто во всех мануалах для yii указывается путь к папке web. Поэтому так сделал

Comment: То что root указывает на папку web, все правильно. А вот папки app у вас нет. От корня проекта у вас есть папка models. Вы делали php yii.php init ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов а у меня нет yii.php?

Comment: @Radzhab немного ошибся php yii init Вот так

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов действительно, оказывается при создании бекапа файл был потерян) добавил и все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c yii не работал очень давно, но можно попробывать взять [официальный гайд для 1.1](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.apache-nginx-config), едва ли конфиг сервера для них отличается

Comment: Алик)?........,,

Comment: @Radzhab :-))))